# What does exactly organic growth mean in context of our site?

Tags: discussion

In many cases, I hear that an SE site should grow organically. Basically I agree with it. Still I would like to understand which factors do influence that process.

One scenario is for example which I can imagine, a user search on a search engine like Google for **"deploy kubernetes"**,  **"devops kubernetes"**. In fact I can't see **not a single SO/SE link** there.

Also, for **"java exception error"** I get one Google result link from SO but it's nevertheless the first one.

So it seems like organic growth does not depend of *googlability* of these sites?